# Is there anything wrong with using byte as enum backing type?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

Given the following program:

```
using System;

namespace VS2012TestApp
{
    class Program
    {
        [Flags]
        public enum IoStatus : byte
        {
            ControlStore = (byte)128,
            Control = (byte)64,
            LogicalState = (byte)32,
            PhysicalState = (byte)16,
            NewEdge = (byte)4,
            Overload = (byte)2,
            NoLoad = (byte)1,
            None = (byte)0,
            Notify = (byte)8,
        }

        private static IoStatus Status = IoStatus.LogicalState;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Process(IoStatus.LogicalState | IoStatus.Overload, IoStatus.None);
        }

        private static void Process(IoStatus bitsSet, IoStatus bitsCleared)
        {
            bitsSet |= Status;
            bitsCleared |= ~Status;

            // Console.WriteLine("set {0}, clear {1}", bitsSet, bitsCleared);

            bitsSet &= ~(IoStatus.LogicalState | IoStatus.PhysicalState);
            bitsCleared &= ~(IoStatus.LogicalState | IoStatus.PhysicalState);

            Console.WriteLine("set {0}, clear {1}", bitsSet, bitsCleared);
        }
    }
}
```

In VS2012 (update 3) on a Win7 x64 bit in Debug mode I get:

> set Overload, clear NoLoad, Overload, NewEdge, Notify, Control, ControlStore

This is what I would expect.

In Release mode (with and without Optimization turned on):

> set Overload, clear None

which is wrong.

Target platform AnyCPU or x86 both result in the same output. The code works fine in VS2008 in Debug and Release mode. Haven't tried VS2010.

**Edit:** Running it in the debugger in release mode produces the correct behaviour.

It can be fixed by doing any of the following:

1. Inserting the (currently commented out) `Console.WriteLine()`
2. Changing the backing type of the `enum` to `int`
3. Changing the code of `Process` to:

   ```
   private static void Process(IoStatus bitsSet, IoStatus bitsCleared)
   {
        bitsSet = (bitsSet | Status) & ~(IoStatus.LogicalState | IoStatus.PhysicalState);
        bitsCleared = (bitsCleared | ~Status) & ~(IoStatus.LogicalState | IoStatus.PhysicalState);

        Console.WriteLine("Set {0}, Clear {1}", bitsSet, bitsCleared);
    }
   ```

So the question is: Are we using enums in a way which they were not intended and just hit an "undefined behaviour" or is this a bug in the compiler/jitter?

Comment: I am not able to reproduce using just the command line compiler (csc.exe). I always get the first output. Are you running the program with or without the debugger attached?

Comment: No debugger attached, run from within VS2012 IDE. Running it in the debugger in Release mode will produce correct behaviour.